# Rails Read and Print integers on web

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to print all n(given integer) subsets, I made my Ruby code, it works but I don't know how to print it and read n form a input box on the browser, I made some research and I didn't find anything useful, so I came to ask here. Thanks.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def Submultimi
    @v = Array.new
    @print = Array.new
    @n=3
    @v[1] = 1
    @k=1
    @ok=1
    @j=0
    while @ok==1
      @print[@j] = 0
      for i in 1..@k
        @print[@j] = @print[@j] * 10 + @v[i]

      end
      @j = @j+1
      puts("\n")

      if @v[@k]==@n && @k==1
        @ok=0
      end

      if @v[@k]==@n && @k!=1
        @k=@k-1
        @v[@k] =@v[@k]+1
      else
        @k=@k+1
        @v[@k]=@v[@k-1]+1
      end

    end
    render text: @print[2]
  end
```

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to print the output in a browser, you'll have to attach the other essential parts of the rails flow: routes and views.  The rails getting started doc walks through this pretty well.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: thanks, I managed to print with <%= @print[i] %> in .html.erb file, but I do not know how to read from a text box